# Is it possible to get application from Nokia e5 device (Symbian S60, 3rd edition)?

Tags: symbian, nokia

Long back I had an application and installed it in my Symbian device (Nokia E5). Now I lost the .sisx file and want the application back.

As per my knowledge, it is very easy to extract application from Android device. 
Similarly, is there some kind of method available for extracting app from Nokia E5 ?

Any help is highly appreciated. 
TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is No you can not. Thus either check the Nokia Store whether the app is still available, or contact the original developer for assistance.

And here's the longer answer:

Basically, if the application is installed into memory card, you could of course find & extract all files from there. But if you simply move to them to other device, they would not work, since the internal drive is not having the check sum etc. files required by the platform security.

Then to get the security stuff work ok, you would need to have the installation file for the app. In theory you could simply make the pkg file and use the files you can extract from the device, and use makesis to create the installation file. And then use signsis to sign it with your own self-made certificate.

This would then only work, if the application only uses capabilities allowing self-signing.

Comment: Dr.Jukka - Can we use "SYMBFS - Symbian Filesystem plugin" to extract files ? It has the capability to fetch files from device I guess. 
If we get access to "c:\sys\bin" of device then is it possible ? 
Pls correct me if I am wrong. TIA.

Comment: Basically, if you could extract the files from internal drive, and place them in other phone, then, in theory it might work. Though have to say that I have never tried it. For the tool, never used it, but would assume that it would not be able to break the platform security. But anyway you could of course try it out and see how it works.

Comment: Yes I agree with your theory. I did some research and found that it is possible after we get root access to phone. But the problem in my case is that I don't have root access to phone. Getting root access is possible but it may lead to phone crash and I can lose app forever.

Comment: Thank you Dr.Jukka for showing interest in this question. Initially I thought I won't find a single person to answer such an old concept question but thanks to guys like you. cheers :)